# Error while using += operator in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, stdstring, qstring

I create a small app in Qt Creator. I wanted this code in my `QDialog` constructor, but it doesn't work.

```
std::string wyniki = "apg -q -n " + n + " -m " + m + " -x " + sx + " -a " + a;
if(exclude != "") wyniki+=" -E " + exclude.toUtf8().constData();
if(a==1)wyniki += " -M " + mode;
std::string result = exec(wyniki.c_str());
ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(qstr(result));
```

Compiler messages:

```
../APG-GUI/scores.cpp: In constructor 'Scores::Scores(QWidget*, int, int, int, int, QString, QString)':
../APG-GUI/scores.cpp:36:45: error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [5]' to binary 'operator+'
     std::string wyniki = "apg -q -n " + n + " -m " + m + " -x " + sx + " -a " + a;
                                             ^
../APG-GUI/scores.cpp:37:67: error: invalid operands of types 'const char [5]' and 'const char*' to binary 'operator+'
     if(exclude != "") wyniki+=" -E " + exclude.toUtf8().constData();
                                                                   ^
../APG-GUI/scores.cpp:38:20: error: no match for 'operator+=' (operand types are 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and 'const QString')
     if(a==1)wyniki += " -M " + mode;
                    ^
../APG-GUI/scores.cpp:38:20: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:52:0,
                 from /opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qstring.h:50,
                 from /opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:49,
                 from /opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qwidget.h:46,
                 from /opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qdialog.h:45,
                 from /opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/QDialog:1,
                 from ../APG-GUI/scores.h:4,
                 from ../APG-GUI/scores.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_string.h:949:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator+=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
       operator+=(const basic_string& __str)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_string.h:949:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const QString' to 'const std::basic_string<char>&'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_string.h:958:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator+=(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
       operator+=(const _CharT* __s)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_string.h:958:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const QString' to 'const char*'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_string.h:967:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator+=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
       operator+=(_CharT __c)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_string.h:967:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const QString' to 'char'
../APG-GUI/scores.cpp:39:45: error: no matching function for call to 'Scores::exec(const char*)'
     std::string result = exec(wyniki.c_str());
                                             ^
../APG-GUI/scores.cpp:39:45: note: candidate is:
In file included from /opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/QDialog:1:0,
                 from ../APG-GUI/scores.h:4,
                 from ../APG-GUI/scores.cpp:1:
/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qdialog.h:93:17: note: virtual int QDialog::exec()
     virtual int exec();
                 ^
/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qdialog.h:93:17: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
../APG-GUI/scores.cpp:40:48: error: 'qstr' was not declared in this scope
     ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(qstr(result));
```

I exactly do not know reasons of that malfunction. Why I can't use `=+` operator? That's built-into the C++! Everything I have (I think I have) propely declared and checked that to times. I am beginner to Qt, so maybe I did something wrong. I was looking for solution in Internet, but, unfortunately, didn't find anything according to my problem. Below I post header's I use and variables declarations:

```
#include "scores.h"
#include "cstdio"
#include "ui_scores.h"
#include "cstdlib"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
int n,m,sx,a;
QString mode, exclude;
```

My constructor code (which includes "bad" lines):

```
Scores::Scores(QWidget *parent, int nk, int mk, int xk, int ak, QString modesk, QString excludek) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Scores)
{
    n = nk;
    m = mk;
    a = ak;
    mode = modesk;
    sx = xk;
    exclude = excludek;
    ui->setupUi(this);
    std::string wyniki = std::string("apg -q -n ") + n + " -m " + m + " -x " + sx + " -a " + a; //badline
    if(exclude != "") wyniki+=" -E " + exclude.toUtf8().constData(); //badline
    if(a==1)wyniki += " -M " + mode; //badline 
    std::string result = exec(wyniki.c_str()); //badline
    ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(qstr(result));
}
```

Comment: It is not built into C++, but the standard library, but you need to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). What is `n`, `m`, etc?

Comment: Read the error messages carefully. They are telling you exactly what is going on.

Comment: @FinalContest I gave you the list of my variables

Comment: @Ty221: I mean give a self-explanatory code that can be compiled not chunks in reverse order and all that.

Comment: You mix QString with std::string and even QByteArray, no wonder you get this errors. Why not stick to one and convert everything in one step at the end into the correct format.

Comment: @Flovdis: he may get the strings from different sources from different types. That is not the main issue here. The error is obvious as juanchopanza claimed, but I am surprised that OP does not supply a self-sufficient code that reproduces the issue. IMHO, such ops do not deserve help.

Comment: @Flovdis Do you mean I should cast everything to `std::string` like: `std::string s = (std::string)"apg -n" + (std::string)x + ...`

Comment: @FinalContest Yes, this is clear to me. But this is horrible code! If he is using Qt, he should use a `QString` to combine all strings from the various sources, because at the end he needs a `QString` as result. Horrible code, it hurts my eyes and my heart...

Comment: @Ty221 Yes, declare a `QString result;` at the begin, then use e.g. `result += xxx` to add all parts. Or use the `.arg()` operators. Or you can use a `QTextStream`.

Comment: @Ty221 I posted an example how to assemble strings in Qt using the `.arg()` functions or using a `QTextStream`. Both methods are great is you are mixing a lot of different types. To use the `std::string` with a `.arg()` use the `.c_str()` method.

Comment: The problem is caused by first line and not but mixing with QString yet!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I am impressed the question is not yet closed. It is too broad, asking several different things without a clear SSCCE, and to be honest each issue separately is already duplicate. Having that said, I was the only upvoter. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QString` as primary string type:

```
QString result = QString("apg -q -n %1 -x %2 -y %3").arg(n).arg(x).arg(y);
```

Or use a `QTextStream` to assemble everything.

```
QString result;
QTextStream ts(&result);
ts << "apg -q -n " << n << " -x " << x;
```

To use `std::string` with `.arg()`:

```
std::string x = "xxx";
QString result = QString("xxx -x %1").arg(x.c_str());
```

See the Qt documentation for details about `QString` and `QTextStream`.

Comment: The problem is not with using std::string. It can be used properly.

Comment: @FinalContest Sure you **can** use `std::string` but he is writing a Qt application, so he **should not** use `std::string` to assemble the result. He should use `QString` instead.

Comment: why is that? Because you like QString? He may not prefer something else than your preference?

Comment: In fact, I also prefer std::string instead of QString at times since it is less bloated, not requiring a Qt application instance, and so on.

Comment: The only problem with `std::string` is that it's next to useless in real life. It looks good only on paper, but when you actually need to use it to manipulate real strings, you end up reimplementing everything that `QString` provides and `std::string` misses. Heck, a lot of the stuff provided by `QChar` is not there either. It's kinda important when you write something more than academic exercises...

Comment: Or, to rephrase: I don't know what problems `std::string` is intending to solve, but it sure as heck isn't anything that I actually need. Whereas `QString`'s API seems to be somewhat directed by what people need in real life, not when sitting on a standardization committee :)

Answer (score -1):

Substitute this statement

```
std::string wyniki = "apg -q -n " + n + " -m " + m + " -x " + sx + " -a " + a;
```

for

```
std::string wyniki = std::string( "apg -q -n " ) + n + " -m " + m + " -x " + sx + " -a " + a;
```

provided that all operands have type either char[] or char *.

Otherwise if for example variable n has type int then write

```
std::string wyniki = "apg -q -n " + std::to_string( n ) + " -m " + m + " -x " + sx + " -a " + a;
```

Take into account that only objects of type std::string have overloaded operator +.

After you updated your post then your "bad line" has to look as

```
std::string wyniki = "apg -q -n " + std::to_string( n ) + " -m " + 
                     std::to_string( m ) + " -x " + 
                     std::to_string( sx ) + " -a " + std::to_string( a );
```

If QString has an implicit conversion operator to `const char *` then instead of

```
if(a==1)wyniki += " -M " + mode; //badline
```

you have to write

```
if(a==1)wyniki += std::string( " -M " ) + mode;
```

Comment: This is wrong an answer because the int is still there without conversion.

Comment: Yes, after my post, sure, and I even appreciate that... However, even then, this answer does not address all the bad lines, and everything in the beginning is non-working red-herring.

Comment: @Ty221 See my post. I showed how to change the "bad line",

Comment: 1) Yes, I know. I provided the solution before, too, but decided to remove. :) 2) I do not like `std::`, sorry. It is silly to repeat that many times. 3) I do not think this question should deserve any help. 4) You still do not address all the "bad" lines.